# How to know if my element is overflowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a slider that contains N elements. Each element will by translated by N pixels when the user click on the next button. When the element is out of the wrapper div, it disappears because it is overflowed by another element.

My plugin does not use any margins, just the transform property.

I would like to know if there is a way to know if my element is out of the div. :visible does not work for my problem because the element is already visible but overflowed.

Comment: can you show a fiddle or demo

Comment: You can check for classes that are being added to hidden elements - if any are added, and then target those this way.

Comment: Unfortunately no class is added to the hidden element. It's the only problem with Flickity plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, one way to do it would be to compare the position of this element to the size (width/height or both) of his parent.

With Jquery you could do it this way:

```html
<script>
  //This is the position of the right side of the element 
  //relative to his parent
  var rightPos = $("#element").position().left + $("#element").width();
  //And bottom side
  var botPos = $("#element").position().top + $("#element").height();
  if (rightPos > $("#element").parent().width()) {
    //The element is outside the right limit of the the parent block
  } else if (botPos > $("#element").parent.height()) {
    //It's outside the bottom limit of the parent block
  }
</script>
```

If it's not the parent you could then adapt this code to compare the position to the width of the correct div, preferably by using the jquery offset() method instead of position().

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work with a slider that use "translate X" to move the elements.

Answer (score 1):

By determine `parent` `width` and get `child` `width` then use `if condition`

```
if($('span').width() > divWidth){
alert('Overflowed!');
// do something!
}
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v0o653wz/)**

if you update your question with your `html` then I can update with your codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the wrapper div the CSS property of overflow: hidden

This would mean that any elements inside of it are not visible when they leave the bounds of the wrapper.

Otherwise you could check whether your element is outside of the wrapper div using jQuery to compare the position to that of the parent.

Comment: Yes the wrapper contains the property. but I need to know if an element is overflowed by the wrapper to make some process on it. EDIT: I'll try this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice tool for testing if an element is visible on the screen.

[Detect if a DOM Element is Truly Visible](http://www.useallfive.com/thoughts/javascript-tool-detect-if-a-dom-element-is-truly-visible/)

It looks at an object and checks each of its parents to see if it’s still visible to the user.